# Http PUT in body body: Bad request error, can't parse API token

Tags: java, json, parsing, http-put, frombodyattribute

I've got a big trouble parsing and sending request.
In body of request I have to send a token that I've already got successfully while authetification.
Here's a doc:

> PUT /api/ver1/orders {"token" : String, "order" : Object}

And here's how I parsing and getting JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put(ICConst.ORDER_TYPE, 1);
params.put(ICConst.PAYMENT, 2);
params.put(ICConst.ORDER_NAME, ICApplication.currentOrder .getOrderName());
params.put(ICConst.ORDER_DESCRIPTION, ICApplication.currentOrder .getOrderDescription());

JSONObject addressFrom = new JSONObject();
addressFrom.put(ICConst.CITY_FROM, ICApplication.currentOrder .getCityFrom());
addressFrom.put(ICConst.ADDRESS_FROM, ICApplication.currentOrder .getAddressFrom());
params.put(ICConst.FROM, addressFrom);

JSONObject periodFrom = new JSONObject();
periodFrom.put(ICConst.DATE_FROM, ICApplication.currentOrder .getDateFrom());
periodFrom.put(ICConst.TIME_FROM_START, ICApplication.currentOrder .getTimeFromStart());
periodFrom.put(ICConst.TIME_FROM_TILL, ICApplication.currentOrder .getTimeFromTill());
params.put(ICConst.FROM_PERIOD, periodFrom);

JSONObject addressTo = new JSONObject();
addressTo.put(ICConst.CITY_TO, ICApplication.currentOrder .getCityTo());
addressTo.put(ICConst.ADDRESS_TO, ICApplication.currentOrder .getAddressTo());
params.put(ICConst.TO, addressTo);

JSONObject periodTo = new JSONObject();
periodTo.put(ICConst.DATE_TO, ICApplication.currentOrder .getDateTo());
periodTo.put(ICConst.TIME_TO_START, ICApplication.currentOrder .getTimeToStart());
periodTo.put(ICConst.TIME_TO_TILL, ICApplication.currentOrder .getTimeToTill());
params.put(ICConst.TO_PERIOD, periodTo);

JSONObject sender = new JSONObject();
JSONArray senderPhone = new JSONArray();
sender.put(ICConst.SENDER_NAME, ICApplication.currentOrder .getSenderName());
senderPhone.put(0, ICApplication.currentOrder .getSenderPhone());
sender.put(ICConst.SENDER_PHONE, senderPhone);
params.put(ICConst.SENDER, sender);

JSONObject recipient = new JSONObject();
JSONArray recipientPhone = new JSONArray();
recipient.put(ICConst.RECIPIENT_NAME, ICApplication.currentOrder .getRecipientName());
recipientPhone.put(0, ICApplication.currentOrder .getRecipientPhone());
recipient.put(ICConst.RECIPIENT_PHONE, recipientPhone);
params.put(ICConst.RECIPIENT, recipient);

JSONObject receiver = new JSONObject();
receiver.put(ICConst.RECEIVED_NAME, ICApplication.currentOrder .getReceiverComment());
receiver.put(ICConst.RECEIVED_COMMENT, ICApplication.currentOrder .getReceiverComment());
params.put(ICConst.RECEIVED_BY, receiver);

params.put(ICConst.CARGO, getCargo());
jsonObject.put("order", params);
jsonObject.put("token", ICApplication.currentProfile.getToken());
```

And here's Httpput request

```
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(getAbsoluteUrl(url));
httpPut.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
String str = String.valueOf(jsonObject);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(str, "UTF-8");
entity.setContentType("application/json");
entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPut.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
String request = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
Log.v("requestStringEntity", entity + "!");
Log.v("request", request + "!");
```

Another variant is while I'm using com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.
I don't another *get, patch and post* requests and everything was successfully working except *PUT*.
Here's the code I've got:

```
public static void put(Context context, String url, JSONObject jsonObject, AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler) {

StringEntity entity = null;
try {
    entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
    entity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
    entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException _e) {
    _e.printStackTrace();
}
client.setURLEncodingEnabled(true);
client.put(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), entity, "application/json", handler);
}
```

here's entuty/jsonObject String:

> {"token":"b695911b-2973-11e6-acac-06b720391567","order":{"order_type":"1","payment_type":"2","name":"Какой-то
>   груз","cost":"350","description":"","from":{"latitude":"55.15919993700593","longitude":"65.15919993700593"},"fromPeriod":{"date":"1464944049","from":"15","to":"18"},"to":{"city":"Челябинск","address":"Ленина,
>   3,
>   3"},"toPeriod":{"date":"1464944075","from":"15","to":"18:30"},"sender":{"name":"Попов","comment":"Попов","phone":["+70000009111"]},"recipient":{"name":"Иванов
>   Иван Иваныч","comment":"Иванов Иван
>   Иваныч","phone":["70000009112"]},"cargo":[{"name":"wwww","description":"wwww","size":{"height":"2","width":"3","length":"4"},"loaders_count":"1","does_need_packaging":false}]}}

I'm not a professional in Rest and httprequest so I've got no idea what the problem is and still have got an exception in the first put method:

> {"name":"Bad Request","message":"No API token
>   found","code":0,"status":400,"type":"yii\web\HttpException"}

Please if anyone has an idea help me!

Comment: Could you come up with a minimal example?

Comment: @fmarc, what example do you mean?

Comment: I mean a smaller example. Someone trying to answer your question will find it easier to understand the issue if your example code is smaller.

Comment: What is the JSON that is posted? You give the code to create it but not the actual document itself. The problem is in the generated document.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, instead of

```
String str = String.valueOf(params);
```

I think it should be

```
String str = String.valueOf(jsonObject);
```

Because you are adding your token to jsonObject and not params.

Comment: Print your jsonObject and see whether "token" is present in the json which you are posting.

Comment: Couple of things
1 - Should the token value be passed as String?
2 - Are you sure that its "token" only and not "access-token" or something else?
3- Try setting `httpPut.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");`
I can't help you out with limited information about api.

Comment: 1,2 - i have already successful request where i used this token as String everywhere 3. ok I'll try this

Comment: the entity/jsonObject i logged and you can see it in edited above in main question

Comment: Try posting same json using postman or any rest client. If you can successfully post there then there might be issues with your java implementation.